# How to count the number of terms in a taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have a custom post type "Services".  It has a hierarchal taxonomy of "service-category".  Service-category has both parent and child terms.

I need to count the number of parent terms in the taxonomy.  NOT posts.  The # of terms in the taxonomy is being used in my code to layout the page in a recursive loop.

Everything I have researched is about the number of posts per term, not the number of terms in the taxonomy..  I am sure I am missing an obvious way of doing this, but I haven't run across it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you tried using  wp_count_terms?http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_terms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @shanebp suggests, you could use [`wp_count_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_terms) like this:

```
$numTerms = wp_count_terms( 'service-category', array(
    'hide_empty'=> false,
    'parent'    => 0
) );
```

The above will list All top parent terms, empty or not. This function uses [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) functions arguments which can be found in the link or the arguments below:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'           => 'name', 
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'        => true, 
    'exclude'           => array(), 
    'exclude_tree'      => array(), 
    'include'           => array(),
    'number'            => '', 
    'fields'            => 'all', 
    'slug'              => '', 
    'parent'            => '',
    'hierarchical'      => true, 
    'child_of'          => 0, 
    'get'               => '', 
    'name__like'        => '',
    'description__like' => '',
    'pad_counts'        => false, 
    'offset'            => '', 
    'search'            => '', 
    'cache_domain'      => 'core'
);
```

Comment: I made two edits to your code and then it works.  Missing a comma between 'service-category' and array.  Added 'parent'=>0 to limit the count to parent terms only.  Without this the count also included the child terms and I only want parents.  I will mark your answer as correct.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Untested but should work -- get_the_terms returns an array with each term, and then sizeof() counts it, returning an integer. The variable $number will return an integer corresponding to the number of terms.

```
$terms = get_the_terms ( $post->ID, 'service-category' );
$number = sizeof ($terms);
echo $number;

if ( $number == XX ) {
// do something
}
```

Comment: That is only returning the number 1.  I also tried changing 'sizeof' to 'count' with the same result.  Also tried using get_terms instead of get_the_terms.  No joy.

Comment: Hmmm. Just tested on my end and it works. Maybe you should double check the taxonomy name.

Comment: @EdwardR.Jenkins your code checks the terms for the given post, not every term of the taxonomy.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the original question. Sorry.